# Why are bones not connected both in rest and pose position?

Tags: bones, pose-mode

I was making a simple character to learn animation and how to use bones (I'm a beginner), I accidentally made a rotation that I didn't like, so I cleared the transforms, but it is different from the rest position. I looked closely and realised that two bones that *are* connected in pose position are *not* connected in rest position (pictures attached) what do I do to fix this?

here are "side by side"s

*close up with bones showing*[image: note the separation]

*what it looks like in full view*

[image: full effect]

[image]

thanks

Comment: please share your file so that we can see the bones setup: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ok thanks! i didnt know i could do that, (i'm a beginner) anyway, would you be able to help me now? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you are in *Pose* mode, the *Rest Position* put the bones at the same positions as in *Edit* mode. If you switch back to *Pose Position* you'll let all the *Bone Constraints* (and perhaps keyframes) act on your bones.

In your case, why, in *Pose Position*, is the calf bone in another position than in *Edit* mode (or *Rest Position*)? Because it has an *IK Constraint* and you can see the influence of this constraint, it will make the bone stick to its target, which is called "leg_ik.l".

So if you don't want your basic *Pose* mode to be this one, you need to stick your "leg_ik.l" to the tail of the calf (but in the process it will move some other bones so you will have to bring other corrections).

Comment: wow, thanks so much! i tried that and, you were totally right, it moved other bones, im having trouble with the 'corrections' though :( thanks again!!! but btw, if i wanted to animate this now (say, a walk cycle) would this problem that i have even make a huge difference? or could i just get away without all this hassle?

Comment: I haven't tried this kind of bones setup so I'm not sure how it works, it seems to work once you've fixed the problems you've pointed out, in my case I've tried more basic riggings that work perfectly: just an IK bone (calf), an IK controller behind the foot, this controller is only parented to the main root bone and foot is parented to this controller (and toe parented to foot), and a pole target for the knee of course, it's easy

Comment: like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU except I create a toe bone (so 2 bones for the foot), and no need for custom bones in my opinion but that's a detail